# how can i add plyr.io download button and progress thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html5-video

i am using plyr.io for my videos. and i need to add download button at bottom and also need on progress show thumbnails like youtube progress thumbnails, is it possible to add ? or we can you any other plugin? if have any plugin for integrate in current plyr.io player so please share with me thanks.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
  // This is the bare minimum JavaScript. You can opt to pass no arguments to setup.
  const player = new Plyr('#player');
  
  // Expose
  window.player = player;

  // Bind event listener
  function on(selector, type, callback) {
    document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(type, callback, false);
  }

  // Play
  on('.js-play', 'click', () => { 
    player.play();
  });

  // Pause
  on('.js-pause', 'click', () => { 
    player.pause();
  });

  // Stop
  on('.js-stop', 'click', () => { 
    player.stop();
  });

  // Rewind
  on('.js-rewind', 'click', () => { 
    player.rewind();
  });

  // Forward
  on('.js-forward', 'click', () => { 
    player.forward();
  });
});
```

```css
/* This is purely for the demo */
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.plyr {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.6/plyr.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.6/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg" id="player">
                <!-- Video files -->
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="576">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="720">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1440p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1440">

                <!-- Caption files -->
                <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt"
                    default>
                <track kind="captions" label="Français" srclang="fr" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.fr.vtt">

                <!-- Fallback for browsers that don't support the <video> element -->
                <a href="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" download>Download</a>
            </video>
  
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="button" class="btn js-play">Play</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-pause">Pause</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-stop">Stop</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-rewind">Rewind</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn js-forward">Forward</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can add a download button by adding it to the list of [controls](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/blob/master/controls.md) you want to show:

```js
const player = new Plyr('#player', {
     // Default controls
    controls: [
        'play-large',
        // 'restart',
        // 'rewind',
        'play',
        // 'fast-forward',
        'progress',
        'current-time',
        'mute',
        'volume',
        'captions',
        'settings',
        'pip',
        'airplay',
        'download',
        'fullscreen',
    ],
});
```

For the thumbnails on seek/scrubber there is an [open request](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1159), but no updates... so unless someone wants to contribute one it may be a while.

**Update** [Dec 13 2018]: looks like there's a [PR](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/1159#issuecomment-446419261) to support thumbnails on the scrubber/seekbar that's looking good
**Update** [Jan 5 2019]: looks like the change has been [merged](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/pull/1253)